# Extracting substring from a String in Json Format in Java

Tags: java, json, string, parsing, substring

I have this string

`String str= " {\"name\":\"xyz\",\"id\":\"123\" } ";`

I want to extract `xyz` from the given string, can someone please suggest an efficient way of doing it in Java?

Comment: I suggest you should start to write some code and then check the efficiency. Where is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to parse the whole JSON into an object, you can do this with [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath).

```
String str = " {\"name\":\"xyz\",\"id\":\"123\" } ";
String name = JsonPath.read(str,"$.name");
System.out.println(name);
```

Add the following dependency to your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step1**: Create Some DTO class like below

```
public class MyDTO{
  private String name;
  private String id;

  // Create setters and getters
}
```

**Step2**: Convert above string to DTO(pojo class) class by using objectmapper like below

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String str= "{\"name\":\"xyz\",\"id\":\"123\"}";
MyDTO dto = objectMapper.readValue(str, MyDTO.class);
```

**Step3**: After converting to DTO object you can use it with dto object like below.

```
System.out.println(dto.getName());
```

**Note**: If you don't have fasterxml dependency in your pom file then add the below dependency to your pom file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Happy coading..!